# How can redirect users just once and if they want they can come back to page without redirect again

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, cookies

I have this redirection in my index.php wordpress site
it redirect users with bulgarian ip to my local site
can this script be turned off for users that already have been redirected once
I want users that have been redirected and want to read the english version 
to be able to read it and not be redirected again.

```
<?php

  $server   = 'test'; // MySQL hostname
  $username = 'test'; // MySQL username
  $password = 'test'; // MySQL password
  $dbname   = 'test'; // MySQL db name


  $db = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

  $sql = 'SELECT 
              country
          FROM 
              ip2nation
          WHERE 
              ip < INET_ATON("'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'") 
          ORDER BY 
              ip DESC 
          LIMIT 0,1';

  list($country) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($sql));

  switch ($country) {
    case 'bg':
      // Get the bg to a bg site
      header('Location: http://bg.test.com');
      exit;     
  }
```

How can I do it with cookie or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<?php

  [.....]

  list($country) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($sql));

  /* ****** NEW CODE ******* */
  if ( isset( $_COOKIE['bg_redirect'] ) && $_COOKIE['bg_redirect'] == 'true' ){
      // cookie exists! user has already been sent once
      $country = ''; // reset so it's NOT 'bg'
  }

  switch ($country) {
    case 'bg':

      /* ****** NEW CODE ******* */
      // set cookie
      setcookie( 'bg_redirect', 'true', time()+ 86400 ); // set cookie for 24 hours

      // Get the bg to a bg site
      header('Location: http://bg.test.com');
      exit;


  }
```

You could also show a link for your visitors who have been redirected, to reset like this:

```
<?php if ( isset( $_COOKIE['bg_redirect'] ) ) { ?>
<a href="/?reset=true">Back to BG</a>
<?php } ?>
```

and then at the very top of your code:

```
<?php

if ( isset( $_REQUEST['reset'] ) ){
    // expire cookie
    unset($_COOKIE['bg_redirect']);
    setcookie( 'bg_redirect', null, -1 );
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much!
Can I do it every time when someone go to test.com with bg IP he is redirected to bg.test.com but he can click a link to test.com and stay there. And next time he go to test.com he is redirected again?

Comment: bg user land on test.com and he is redirected to bg.test.com
after that he click on en flag and go to test.com (en site) and stay there  (that is DONE with previous code and thank you for that)
Can it be done when this bg user open test.com again no mather when he is redirected again to bg.test.com (he can go to en version only when he click en flag in bg version)